# Read rows and cols from matrix out of a file

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic, readfile

I have a Python script which generates a Matrix with double values and saves them in a txt file like this:

> -5.70683 -9.72438 5.62137 -3.52453
>
> -3.70381 7.25433 -4.21905 3.88678
>
> -1.43741 7.39768 -6.84103 -3.45817
>
> -5.66966 3.47989 -5.64204 -6.08512

Now I have to read the .txt file in a C file and convert it to my struct:

```
struct Matrix {
    int rows;
    int columns;
    double **matrix;
};
```

This is my C file:

```
Matrix *readMatrix(const char filename[]) {
    Matrix matrix;
    FILE * matrix_file;
    char * str;
    int i, j;

    //allocate pointer
    matrix.matrix = malloc(4 * sizeof(double *));
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        matrix.matrix[i] = malloc(4 * sizeof(double *));

    matrix_file = fopen(filename, "r");

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (!fscanf(matrix_file, "%lf", &matrix.matrix[i][j]))
                break;

            printf("%lf\n",matrix.matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(matrix_file);
    return &matrix;
}
```

Instead of allocate it to a 4x4 matrix I want to allocate my Pointer dynamic. So I have to read out of my file the rows and cols. How can I do this?

Comment: `matrix.matrix = malloc(4 * sizeof(double));` should be `matrix.matrix = malloc(4 * sizeof(double *));` (that would probably work, but...). What is your question by the way?

Comment: Terrible condition `!fscanf(matrix_file, "%lf", &matrix.matrix[i][j])`: [READ THE MANUAL](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). Or the standard specificiation for it.

Comment: Obvious question is obvious: can you modify the python script to write the number of rows and columns at the top of the file?

Comment: Also, if this code compiles as it is it must be a [tag:c++] compiler. Because there is no `Matrix` type in your code. And more important is, you should know that `Matrix matrix` as allocated in the function, is only valid within the function. It's deallocated when the function returns so `return &matrix;` is wrong. Your code also lacks `fclose()` if you process many files with it, it will suddenly stop because there is a limit for open file descriptors for a given program.

Comment: Also, remember that a `n x m` matrix will have`nm` elements, thus you need to ensure that you allocate enough memory for the matrix, vis, `matrix = malloc(n * m * sizeof(double));`.  This is of course assuming you are storing the actual values in the matrix and not pointers to the values.

Comment: Why not use a 2D array? `double **` is not a 2D array, nor can it point to one or represent one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not know *a priori* the number of rows and cols and want to deduce it from the file, a simple way would be to:

- read first line, parse it and deduce the number of cols, say M
- allocate an array of N=M arrays of M doubles -> if allocation error, then fatal error
- store values from the first line in the first row of the array
- loop:

  - read a new line and parse it -> if empty line or end of file return the matrix (**not** its address!)
  - ensure that it contains M elements -> if not fatal error
  - if there is no more place in the array realloc with new size being N = 2 * N or N = N + M

    - if allocation error, then fatal error
  - store values from the line in next row

Here is an example of possible code:

```
typedef struct _Matrix {
    int rows;
    int columns;
    double ** matrix; // a pointer to an array of pointers is not a pointer to a 2D array!
    double *data;     // pointer to a 2D array
} Matrix;

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 256

const char delim[] = " \t";

/*
Find the number of double presents on a line 
*/
int getColumns(char *line) {
    char *ix;
    int cols = 0;
    double val;

    ix = strtok(line, delim);
    for (;;) {
        if(ix == NULL) break;
        if (sscanf(ix, "%lg", &val) == 1) {
            cols +=1;
        }
        else break;
        ix = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    return cols;
}

/*
Parse a line on which strtok has been used to find the number of elements
*/
int parseLine(char * line, int ncols, double *val) {
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<ncols; i++) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%lg", val) != 1) return 0;
        line += strlen(line) + 1;  /* skip over the null put here by strtok */
        val += 1;
    }
    return 1;
}

/*
Return (by value) a matrix read from an already opened file
The elements data and matrix must be freed by caller if they are not null
rows is 0 if file is empty, -1 if it is incorrect
*/
Matrix readMatrix(FILE *fd) {
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    Matrix matrix;
    int maxrows, row = 0;
    double *val;  /* val will point the the beginning of the next row */

    /* initializes the matrix */
    matrix.rows = matrix.columns = 0;
    matrix.matrix = matrix.data = NULL;

    /* process first line to discover the number of columns */
    if (NULL == fgets(line, sizeof(line), fd)) return matrix;

    matrix.columns = getColumns(line);
    maxrows = matrix.columns;

    /* allocate the 2D array for data and 1D array of pointers for matrix
    (to be able to use matrix.matrix[row][col] instead of
    matrix.data[col + row.matrix.columns])
    */
    matrix.matrix = malloc(maxrows * sizeof(double *));
    val = matrix.data = malloc(maxrows * matrix.columns * sizeof(double));

    if (parseLine(line, matrix.columns, val) == 0) {
        matrix.rows = -1;
        return matrix;
    }
    /* Ok one row have been read */
    matrix.matrix[matrix.rows++] = val;
    val += matrix.columns;

    /* let's process the other rows */
    for(;;) {
        int cols;
        if (NULL == fgets(line, sizeof(line), fd)) return matrix;
        cols = getColumns(line);
        if (cols == 0) return matrix; /* empty line denotes also the end of data to allow and empty last line */
        if (cols != matrix.columns) {
            matrix.rows = -1; /* incorrect number of cols: fatal */
            return matrix;
        }
        if (matrix.rows == maxrows) { /* data is full: reallocate some more room */
            int r;
            maxrows += matrix.columns;
            matrix.matrix = realloc(matrix.matrix, maxrows * sizeof(double *));
            matrix.data = realloc(matrix.data, maxrows * matrix.columns * sizeof(double));
            for (r=0; r<matrix.rows; r++) {      /* ensure that the pointers from matrix actually point in data */
                matrix.matrix[r] = matrix.data + r * matrix.columns;
            }
            val = matrix.data + matrix.rows * matrix.columns; /* ensure val points to the beginning of next row */
        }
        /* Ok, load the line */
        matrix.matrix[matrix.rows++] = val;
        if (parseLine(line, matrix.columns, val) == 0) {
            matrix.rows = -1;
            return matrix;
        }
        val += matrix.columns;
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

The allocation errors should be tested...

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I just wrote something similar to what you ask.  However, I wrote it in C++ not C, although most of the logic should be similar.  So, while not a complete answer this should be able to guide you a bit.

Note: I was working with square matrices, and my file a comma delimited (not space), and the first line contained the number of rows in the file.  Final note, this was for personal use (as opposed to homework or production code), so a good number of error checking and handling is ignored.

So, for what is is worth, here is an abbreviated version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


#include <string.h>
#include <random>
#include <math.h>

inline int makeNdx(int r, int c, int max) { return r*max + c;}

int populateMatrix(double**);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned int      nSize;
    double*           tmatrix = nullptr;

    if(0 != (nSize = populateMatrix(&tmatrix)))
    {
         // the matrix was manipulated here, this code not relevant to 
         // the answer...
    }

    if(nullptr != tmatrix) delete [] tmatrix;
    return 0;
}


int populateMatrix(double** ppmat)
{
    std::string   strFileName;
    std::string   strLine;
    std::string   token;
    unsigned int  row = 0;
    unsigned int  size = 0;
    int*          pnorms = nullptr;

    if(nullptr != *ppmat) delete [] *ppmat;

    std::cout << "Enter the name of the data file: ";
    std::cin >> strFileName;

    std::ifstream infile(strFileName);

    // read file and get matrix size...
    getline(infile, strLine);
    size = atoi(strLine.c_str());

    // allocate space for matrix...
    *ppmat = new double[size*size];

    while(infile.good())
    {
        getline(infile, strLine);
        std::istringstream  strStream(strLine);

        for(unsigned int col = 0; col < size; col++)
        {
            if(strStream)
            {
                getline(strStream, token, ',');
                (*ppmat)[makeNdx(row, col, size)] = atoi(token.c_str());
            }
        }
        row++;
    }
    return size;
}
```

So, as you can see, I represented the matrix as a 2-dimensional array of doubles.  Because I wanted my populate matrix function to be able to created the matrix (i.e. be able to modify the `tmatrix` value) I needed to pass the pointer by reference to the function, thus why I passed it as a pointer-to-a-pointer.

Remember that in C (and C++) two dimensional arrays are implemented in row-major form, think of one big array where the first row is placed, then the second row and so on.  Thus, because I prefer to think in terms of rows and column I have a utility function to convert a row / column index into the appropriate index into a one-dimensional array.